# Emails errors and not being sent due without any custom templates

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates

I'm on Magento 1.9.* and my emails are failing because of this error:

Exception: This letter cannot be sent. in public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php:385

On further review this code is returning false because getTemplateSubject is empty:

```
public function isValidForSend()
{


Mage::log('getTemplateSubject: '.$this->getTemplateSubject(), null, 'email.log'); //EMPTY

   return !Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('system/smtp/disable')
        && $this->getSenderName()
        && $this->getSenderEmail()
        && $this->getTemplateSubject();
}
```

The thing is I don't have any custom templates. When looking at the templates folder @ /public_html/app/locale/en_US/template/email, This is what I see

[image]

I have templates here but they all have a _backup_date.html file associated with it. Is this where my issue lies? What process would do such a thing to rename all these files?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Hi Matt,
    You can copy all Email templates from default magento and if you need content from old backup then just open files one by one and copy and paste in your new email templates.

    Or just rename old backup file matching with magento default files.

    Hope this will help you.
```